# How to convert joda DateTime with timezone to DateTime with same time in UTC?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I have such input date:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime("2022-10-30T00:00:00.000+11:00");
```

How can I convert it to UTC while keeping the same time:`"2022-10-30 00:00:00.000"`?

In other words, I want the `date.getMillis();` method to return the midnight of "2022-10-30" in UTC.

For now, if I call `date.getMillis();`, I get "2020-10-29" in UTC.

Comment: Do you have a strong reason for continuing to use Joda Time, vs the `java.time` package?

Comment: Yes, it is used throughout the project

Comment: I suspect you are looking for [`DateTime.withZoneRetainFields`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withZoneRetainFields-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-).

Comment: "Yes, it is used throughout the project" does the project have a strong reason for the continuing use of Joda Time?

Comment: [The homepage of JodaTime](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) states: *Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.*

Comment: "does the project have a strong reason for the continuing use of Joda Time?"
It's a legacy project and switching to java.time is out of scope for now.

Comment: @jjj does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73701122/how-to-convert-joda-datetime-with-timezone-to-datetime-with-same-time-in-utc#comment130145873_73701122) not work for you?

Comment: @AndyTurner no, I tried `dt.withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone.UTC);`

Comment: @jjj please show how you are determining this. "if I call date.getMillis();, I get "2020-10-29" in UTC" doesn't make sense, because `date.getMillis()` returns a `long`, not any kind of a date, so you must be doing something with that `long` that you're not showing us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you're doing what you think you're doing here.

The date you're creating doesn't have a UTC+11 offset, it's in your JVM's default time zone ([demo](https://onecompiler.com/java/3yfvxz4gu)):

```
System.out.println(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
DateTime date = new DateTime("2022-10-30T00:00:00.000+11:00");
System.out.println(date);
```

prints

```
Etc/UTC
2022-10-29T13:00:00.000Z
```

so the local date portion of this is `2022-10-29`.

If you want to create it with the specified offset, you have to either use `DateTime.parse`:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.parse("2022-10-30T00:00:00.000+11:00");
```

or specify it:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime("2022-10-30T00:00:00.000+11:00", DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(11));
```

Printing either of these results in:

```
2022-10-30T00:00:00.000+11:00
```

Now, `date.withZoneRetainFields(DateTimeZone.UTC)` is:

```
2022-10-30T00:00:00.000Z
```

as required.